# when I got an instantiate object of IScroll, i found the constructor of that instantiate object point to Object rather than IScroll。Why?

Tags: iscroll

I am learning the original code of IScroll.js. And I found the question as the Title.This is the code i exceted[enter image description here][1]

```
var myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', { mouseWheel: true});    myScroll.constructor; // Object myScroll.constructor === Object; //true
```

Comment: Add code as text not as image

Comment: it's the first time asking question on stackoverflow.com 我英语不好，问题也表述得不清楚，不好意思哈，不过我正在学习中